# How can i send JSON String using webView.postUrl

Tags: android, webview

i'm able to send json string to webview using webView.postUrl and only getting the data in my php page when i use

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
print base64_decode($postdata);
```

here is my code

```
byte[] encodeValue = Base64.encode(data.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.postUrl("http://example.com/post.php", encodeValue);
```

How can i send it without encoding ?

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) second parameter in webview must be of type `byte` and data must be "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" encoded.

```
void postUrl (String url, byte[] postData)
```

So a small example again on posting

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);    
    String url = "http://example.com/somepage.php";
    String postData = "postvar=value";    
    webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
}
```